# Ubuntu Newrelic package start command not working

Tags: ubuntu, newrelic

I am trying to this command `/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond start`

But it is not working. It give me some error like this.

```
Starting New Relic Server Monitor: newrelic-sysmond FAILED
```

Is it validation errors ?

Here is my local compute information

- OS

  - Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is my bad..

I am removed log directory.

You must set the log location:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/newrelic
sudo chown newrelic:newrelic /var/log/newrelic
```